# Cucumber test cases fail when run together, but they pass when I run them individually

Tags: spring, testing, gradle, intellij-idea, cucumber

I am using Spring with Cucumber (and IntelliJ and Gradle). 
My test case fails when run together and passes when run individually. (The fails 2 out of 3 times, sometimes it works...)

I also tried to quarantine the problematic Scenario or Senario combinations, but no luck...
I tried introducing @After and @Before hooks to reset the value of of the account value...
I even tried switching the position of senarios, nothing helps...

I really hope someone can help me with this problem

**The features:**

```
Feature: Cash Withdrawal
  Scenario: Successful withdrawal from an account in credit
    Given my account has been credited with $100.00
    When I withdraw $20
    Then $20 should be dispensed
    And the balance of my account should be $80.00
  Scenario: Unsuccessful withdrawal due to technical fault
    Given my account is in credit
    But the cash slot has developed a fault
    When I request some of my money
    Then I should see an out-of-order message
    And $0 should be dispensed
    And the balance of my account should be unchanged
  Scenario: Unsuccessful withdrawal due to insufficient ATM funds
    Given my account is in credit
    And the ATM contains $10
    When I withdraw $20
    Then I should see an ask-for-less-money message
    And $0 should be dispensed
    And the balance of my account should be unchanged
```

**And my stepdefinitions:**

```
public class AccountSteps {

    @Autowired
    Account account;

    private Money originalBalance;

    @Given("^my account has been credited with (\\$\\d+\\.\\d+)$")
    public void myAccountHasBeenCreditedWith$(
            @Transform(MoneyConverter.class) Money amount)
            throws Throwable {
        account.credit(amount);
    }

    @Given("^my account is in credit$")
    public void myAccountIsInCredit$() throws Throwable {
        originalBalance = new Money(30, 00);
        account.credit(originalBalance);
    }

    @Then("^the balance of my account should be unchanged$")
    public void theBalanceOfMyAccountShouldBeUnchanged() throws Throwable {

        checkBalanceIs(originalBalance);
    }

    @Then("^the balance of my account should be (\\$\\d+\\.\\d+)$")
    public void theBalanceOfMyAccountShouldBe$(
            @Transform(MoneyConverter.class) Money amount) throws Throwable {

        checkBalanceIs(amount);
    }

    private void checkBalanceIs(Money amount) throws Throwable {
        int timeoutMilliSecs = 3000;
        int pollIntervalMilliSecs = 100;

        while (!account.getBalance().equals(amount) && timeoutMilliSecs > 0) {
            Thread.sleep(pollIntervalMilliSecs);
            timeoutMilliSecs -= pollIntervalMilliSecs;
        }

        Assert.assertEquals(
                "Incorrect account balance -",
                amount,
                account.getBalance());
    }
}

public class CashSlotSteps {

    @Autowired
    TestCashSlot cashSlot;

    @Given("^\\$(\\d+) should be dispensed$")
    public void $ShouldBeDispensed(int dollars) throws Throwable {
        Assert.assertEquals("Incorrect amount dispensed -", dollars,
                cashSlot.getContents());
    }

    @Given("^the cash slot has developed a fault$")
    public void theCashSlotHasDevelopedAFault() throws Throwable {
        cashSlot.injectFault();
    }

    @Given("^the ATM contains \\$(\\d+)$")
    public void theATMContains$(int dollars) throws Throwable {
        cashSlot.load(dollars);
    }
}

public class TellerSteps {

    @Autowired
    private Account account;

    @Autowired
    private AtmUserInterface teller;

    @When("^I withdraw \\$(\\d+)$")
    public void iWithdraw$(int amount) throws Throwable {
        teller.withdrawFrom(account, amount);
    }

    @Given("^I request some of my money$")
    public void iRequestSomeOfMyMoney() {
        int dollarsRequested = 10;
        teller.withdrawFrom(account, dollarsRequested);
    }

    @Then("^I should see an out-of-order message$")
    public void iShouldSeeAnOutOfOrderMessage() throws Throwable {
        Assert.assertTrue(
                "Expected error message not displayed",
                teller.isDisplaying("Out of order"));
    }

    @Then("^I should see an ask-for-less-money message$")
    public void iShouldSeeAnAskForLessMoneyMessage() throws Throwable {
        Assert.assertTrue(
                "Expected error message not displayed",
                teller.isDisplaying("Insufficient ATM funds"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are obviously mutating a variable which is shared between two tests which is not getting reset.

This is usually

1. A static mutable variable
2. A member variable on a singleton service

I'm not sure how you are managing your services but if using spring you might want to investigate [@DirtiesContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html) for case 2. Eg:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={...}) 
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class MyTest { ... }
```

Further info [here](http://www.javarticles.com/2016/03/spring-dirtiescontext-annotation-example.html)

Comment: Please note that this is a Cucumber test. Not a spring test. However Cucumber does support the `@DirtiesContext` annotation.

Comment: You have shown the problem in your other post. You have static services everywhere. This is almost certainly your problem. I suggest you refactor your entire codebase to remove the static services and instead embrace dependency injection. Your application is currently "coupled"

Comment: I'm not the original poster. :D

Comment: I know what you mean, but I prefer not to refactor the hole code, because I try to repeat the given code of the Cucumber for Java book by myself

Answer (score 0):

I have some hooks, for this example. To delete the account.

```
public class ResetHooks {
    @Before(order = 1)
    public void reset() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\...\\geckodriver.exe");
        if (!Base.hasConnection()) {
            Base.open(
                    "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost/bank",
                    "user", "password");
        }

        Account.deleteAll();

        TransactionQueue.clear();
    }

}
```

-------------edit----------

**My Cumcumber xml for spring:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="hooks, nicebank, support" />

    <bean class="support.AtmUserInterface" scope="cucumber-glue" />
    <bean class="support.TestCashSlot" scope="cucumber-glue" />

    <bean class="support.AccountFactory" factory-method="createTestAccount"
          lazy-init="true" scope="cucumber-glue" />

    <bean class="org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver"
          scope="cucumber-glue" destroy-method="close">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver"
                  scope="cucumber-glue"/>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Aarrrggghhh! Run away from that code base! There are static mutable variables everywhere!!!. Base.hasConnection(), Account.deleteAll(), TransactionQueue.clear()... yuck! This will cause you endless headaches in testing. Static services are evil!

Comment: Oh okay... I just start with testing, so I work with the cucumber for Java book. I don't know that this is a worng Idea :(

Comment: Please read up on [dependency injection](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and don't use statics. I'll say it again, static services are evil! Same goes for mutable static state

Comment: I'm going to second that. Cucumber supports dependency injection. There is no good reason to use static services.

Comment: I understand that, but I don't want to renew the whole code of the book, I just starting with testing and want to learn it. I don't know how I can change this now

Comment: It's an awful, awful, awful solution. But if you really want to keep the static services (please please don't) then I suggest you write a `SomeStaticService.reset()` method. This will clean up any "dirty" static state. You could then call this in @Before and/or @After. I can't iterate enough how terrible these static methods are. Your whole application is early bound and tightly coupled.

Comment: @Deviasa which book?

Comment: @mpkorstanje: The Cucumber for Java Book
Behaviour-Driven Development
for Testers and Developers 
from:
Seb Rose
Matt Wynne
Aslak Hellesøy

Comment: Okay. That would have been useful to mention at the start! @lance-java don't worry about the DI. There is a refactor step to DI later on in the book.

Comment: Okay, sorry but I say that in my first comment, but sorry. And what help that?^^

Comment: I mean in the question.

Comment: So does this book start with an ugly, static application and refactor to dependency injection? I hope so

Comment: @Deviasa the lack of dependency injection is a bit of a red herring. It would have helped to clear that up by noting that you were following a book from the start. Never the less, the problem remains the same. You are transferring state between your tests. You'll have to figure out which bit that is. From what you've provided I can't tell.

Comment: The usual approach to solving this is to disable your scenarios one by one until you have a pair left that fails together. Then you debug that pair and ensure the state doesn't carry over.

Comment: Ever pair fails, only if I run them individually, than they passed

Comment: I add the cucumber xml in my comment after ---edit---

Comment: @mpkorstanje where I finde the step in the book, because it still doesn´t work

Comment: @Deviasa if you have a pair of scenarios that fails you can start debugging and work out why the second one fails. The cause of this will probebly another thing that needs to be reset. If you are unfamiliar with debugging it might be a good idea to follow a course on java first. 

It can also help to start over from the code provided by the book. The pre-face in the foot notes has a link to the source.

Comment: Ok i have found the promblem with the help of sleep steps: I have to use account.getBalance instead of credit (but that stnad in the book -.-) Now it works. Thank u!        @Given("^my account is in credit$")
    public void myAccountIsInCredit$() throws Throwable {
        originalBalance = new Money(30, 00);
        account.setBalance(originalBalance);
    }